# Is it possible to render a view from the public folder in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm making a `cms` for a Design-store such as themeforset. I'm using [Laravel 4](http://laravel.com) and I need advice on how I should go about uploading and rendering web templates that the user would upload.

Answer (score 4):

In the `app/config/view.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View Storage Paths
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
| an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
| the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
|
*/

'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),
```

So, you can use/add your own path for views to be loaded from.